# React JS v React Native

Tags: user-interface, meteor, mobile, reactjs, react-native

I am looking to decide what to you to style my meteor application with which I plan to launch solely as an android and iOS app. It will not be made into a website. 
My understanding is react native is the same as reactjs but geared towards mobile apps. Is this this true? If so do you recommend using react native instead of reactjs for making apps or does reactjs still offer greater benefits? 
Also, is material ui or anything like that needed when using react native?

Comment: There is a significant and important difference between React and React Native. React *is* JavaScript, whereas React Native compiles down to either iOS native code (think objective c) or Android (Java). They are not quite the same, but share some of the ways you write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-native shares a mental model with React and some key code, but is significantly different. Here's a few points/differences to consider:

- Runs w/ bridged-code that executes native functionality *not* normally callable by or with JavaScript.
- React and react-dom are meant to run in a DOM environment (react-dom can run server-side, but the apps are meant to run and be interacted w/ primarily in a browser context).
- It allows you share code between platforms, but you *usually* can't and shouldn't expect to have 100% code re-use.
- You can drop to native when appropriate, but in a good situation you can share code more often than not.

Lastly, for material UI, if you're talking about the google material UI, is a stylistic UI lib, not a cross-platform interface library. It's more akin to bootstrap than React. There are plenty of libraries that implement google's material UI, and those might be created specifically for React, React-native or another library/platform.

Hope that helps a bit!